# SQL Server 2005 Analysis Services won't start

Tags: sql-server-2005

We use SQL Server 2005 and sometimes our Analysis Services won't start. A simple reboot solves the problem, however, I'm trying to find a solution that does not rely on that.

If I try to start it from the "SQL Server Configuration Manager", I get a timeout error. When starting from windows' services manager, it states that the service was "started and then interrupted".

The windows application log has three entries:
1 - The flight recorder was started.
2 - The service cannot be started: The following system error occurred: . The following system error occurred: .
3 - Service stopped.

I have also tried to start "Analysis Services" with every single logon option. The same error occurs.

Comment: As a side note: SQL Server 2005 has been totally [out of support since 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%202005). Upgrading to modern version is strongly encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a service restart or a Stop and start in SQL Server Config Manager? I had a similar issue on an old 2005 box and if I did a restart of SQL services in SQL server config manager the issue would not be resolved until I do a Stop and start or reboot the server.